# How can i make a virtual mouse that can be recognized as an external mouse

Tags: python, c++, windows

I have a program that requires mouse movement and I was wondering how to make a virtual mouse that is recognized as an external mouse. Anobody go any ideas?
I tried this code but this is not recognized as an external device.

```
import pyautogui
def func1():
   pyautogui.press("left")
   pyautogui.press("enter")
   pyautogui.moveTo(100, 150)
   keyboard.send("enter")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows virtual mouse driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942366/windows-virtual-mouse-driver) and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/samples/input-driver-samples